# GA4 Custom event tracking with navigation

Tags: angular, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api

I would like to know how to track login success events via GA4. I have successfully configured GA4 in my Angular app and configured a tag to the login button click event via GTM. But the issue is it tracks all the login clicks.

My requirement is that the user clicks on the login button and the web app navigates the user to the home page. That's the way I can assure the user made a successful login.

How do I filter such a scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say you can track a successful login, under where you navigate the user from login to your home/landing page, trigger an event.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on it a bit more? Im brand new to Analytics.

Comment: check this article https://danielk.tech/home/angular-and-google-analytics